# Determine the contents of Linux Cache

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

On a Linux device (using Android [Eclair] with a 2.6.29 kernel), I seem to have some contents in my cache that never go away.

I would like to be able to examine the contents of my cache to find the culprit. I've looked at `mount` for any tmpfs that may be causing it, but they are taking up very little space.

What other types of things could be constantly using up cache?

If there is no built in way to examine the cache, what would be a good function in the kernel to dump information from regarding this? Is there any easy point?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean OS buffer cache or something else? What sort of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The cache referred to in meminfo in the kernel:
  
# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:         177000 kB
MemFree:           80692 kB
Buffers:            2836 kB
Cached:            78164 kB <-- this. 

Android's low memory killer bases its decisions on low MemFree+Cached, so in my case it is never getting low enough to kill anything. I could fix that locally by using higher values, but I would prefer to know what is always taking up the extra cache in the system.

Comment: To ask my question in a slightly different way, I want to know what is in Cache when I do "echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && cat /proc/meminfo" and Cached still shows 6380KB for me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue may derive from `block cache`. Try running `sync` and see if it persists.